# Select all the countries that have a minimum number of clients

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, one is `Countries` that contains `codeCountry` and `nameCountry` and second table `Client` that contains `privat_code_country.` CodeCountry for example AUS and nameCountry Austria.

I want to select all the countries that have a minimum number of clients, in other words, I have to join this two tables and find all the countries that have minumum number of clients.

After I writed a query, I had a problem with "not a single-group group function" .

This is my query:

```
 select codeCountry, min(cnt) as Number_of_clients
from (select s.codeCountry, count(*) as cnt
      from countries s join
           client t
           on s.codeCountry = t.privat_code_country 
      group by s.codeCountry
     ) t order by number_of_clients desc, codeCountry asc;
```

I want to recive all the countries that have minimum number of clients, so what I ask, is to correct my query. TNx

Expected result is :

```
CodeCountry Number    umber_of_clients
AUS                    1     
CRO                    1
ITA                    1
```

Comment: can you correct my query? @lamak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a RANK:

```
select *
from
 (
      select s.codeCountry, count(*) as cnt, 
         rank() over (order by count(*)) as rnk -- rank based on increasing counts
      from countries s join
           client t
           on s.codeCountry = t.privat_code_country 
      group by s.codeCountry
 ) dt 
where rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirly following your logic, your inner query already leave you with 1 record for each codeCountry, so why do you need to choose min(count) ?

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select s.codeCountry, count(*) as number_of_clients 
    from countries s join
           client t
           on s.codeCountry = t.privat_code_country 
    group by s.codeCountry) tt
WHERE tt.number_of_clients = (select min(cnt) from(SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM countries s
                           join client t
                             on s.codeCountry = t.privat_code_country 
                           group by s.codeCountry))
order by tt.codeCountry asc;
```

I think by the look of your data that you don't have to make a join and you can select only from client table:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.codeCountry,count(*) as number_of_clients
    FROM client t
    GROUP BY t.codeCountry) tt
WHERE tt.number_of_clients = (SELECT MIN(cnt) FROM(SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM client
                                                  GROUP BY codeCountry)
                             )
```

Comment: yes, this is almost good, but i have to display just countries that cointains minimum number od clients. Expected result is that must display few countries that have number of clients " 1 " , not 2,3,4...

Comment: " missing right parenthesis" on the bottom of the query, where is order by

Comment: @GoranBartBartolić did you try the second query? and try the first one again.

Comment: " "codeCountry": invalid identifier, before where cnt

Comment: Argh, now @GoranBartBartolić

Comment: I'm sorry, but no. @sagi .. "T"."codeCountry": invalid identifier , just before where... Never mind, thanks you a lot, dnoeth resolved a problem with rank !

Answer (score 2):

If you want the list of countries which share the minimum number of clients:

```
select x.codeCountry, x.cnt as number_of_clients 
from
(
    select t.codeCountry, min(t.cnt) over () as min_cnt, t.cnt
    from
    (
        select s.codeCountry, count(*) as cnt
        from 
        countries s 
        join 
        client t
        on s.codeCountry = t.privat_code_country 
        group by s.codeCountry

    ) t
) x
where x.cnt=x.min_cnt
order by codeCountry asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have understood.

```
select s.codeCountry, count(*) as cnt
  from countries s join client t
           on s.codeCountry = t.privat_code_country 
 group by s.codeCountry
 having count(1) > <the value you consider as minimum>
 order by s.codeCountry asc;
```